# IIS 7.5 MVC 5 deployed website will not connect to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7.5

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 website that works fine when it is running locally, but when deployed to the IIS 7.5 web server, it will not access SQL Server to pull up necessary information for the page.

The error it give says it is not able to get the connection settings from the `web.config` file. When I use the connection settings directly in the DB call, however; I do not get the error, but no information at all is pulled from the DB.

Here is my connection string if that helps:

```
server=servername;database=dbName;uid=Id;pwd=password
```

Can someone give me an idea of how I can correct the error?

Thank you in advance for all your help...

Comment: That's not your entire connection string is it? Because you at least need the provider in there.

Comment: Sorry, Here is the whole string:
<add name="connectionName" connectionString="server=server;database=dbaseName;uid=ID;pwd=password" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: The user of app pool has right to read the web.config ? The connectionString is in the right section inside the web.config ? Can you post the error ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right answer, but I've had problems like this before when going to IIS, and wrote up some notes for myself - https://gilesey.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/allowing-iis-7-5-applications-to-communicate-to-sql-server-via-windows-authentication/

Comment: @Max
Here is the complete error that comes up:
Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I have tracked it back to where it should be using the Connection string from the web.config, but I do not think it is acessing it. How would I check if the App pool has the right to access the web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it ... I believe the problem was that I originally configured it as a web app in the Default website in IIS and it was looking at the web.config for the Default website and not finding the access string it required to access the SQL server.

I made it it's own website and everything is running fine now...